# how to call with variable as key while an array called in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

this works

```
for (var i=1; i<=queueconf.limit; i++)
{

  var filename=queueconf['jobs']['queue1']['name'];
}
```

but, this does not work

```
for (var i=1; i<=queueconf.limit; i++)
{

  //as queue+i
  var filename=queueconf['jobs']['queue'+i]['name'];

  var qfile=require("./jobs/"+filename);
}
```

why?
error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

it sees an error like above code

Comment: Are you sure `queueconf['jobs']` has `queue0`, `queue1`,  etc. properties?

Comment: `['queue'+i]` probably is not valid or not found.

Comment: `i` means, anything between 0 to queueconf.limit. Among which `jobs['queue'+ i ]` might returned `undefined`. Check your `queueconf`

Comment: What type is the queueconf? Is it an array? It seems a bit strange the `queueconf.limit`. Shouldn't it be `queueconf.length`?

Comment: queueconf.limit 1 so that, queue1 it works ,,but queue'+i it does not work..

Comment: If `['queue1']` works, then when `i` is 1 `['queue' + i]` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that not all `queues` (`queues1` to `queuesn`) are available in `queueconf['jobs']`.

try this fail-safe

```
for (var i=1; i<=queueconf.limit; i++)
{
  var queue = queueconf['jobs']['queue'+i];
  if ( queue )
  {
    var filename = queue['name'];
    var qfile = require("./jobs/"+filename);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes yes,,queueconf.limit is false..now it has been worked..thanks